# Understanding the notion of "difference" in Voltage

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, voltage, definition, conventions

Ok I'm having some hard time to grasp the concept of "Voltage". I'm going to refer to 2 videos I watched, although I watched more and read about it, but these two pretty much summarize what I've watched and read.

Ok so [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w82aSjLuD_8&list=RDCMUCk0fGHsCEzGig-rSzkfCjMw&index=4) explains voltage as the force that pushes electrons in a circuit. When we apply voltage to a closed circuit, there is a "pressure" pushing the free electrons in the circuit. It uses the famous water-flow analogy to compare voltage to pressure in a water pipe connected to a bottom of a water tank.

> The more pressure there is - the more water can flow. The more voltage there is - the more electrons can flow

I have some questions about this analogy, but first let's talk about the second video.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBt-kxYfync) explains that voltage is:

> The difference in potential energy, per unit of charge, between two points

This definition is found in many other sources. He further explains that voltage is measured in Joules per Coulomb, and as far as I understand, what this means is that the voltage - the "pressure" - is measured in how much work can a single Coulomb of electrons (or more accurately, an electric charge?) can do.

There are my questions:

1. In the water analogy, we compare electrons to some units of water (let’s say drops of water, let a drop be a small amount of water). So with the water in the tank, the water itself creates the pressure, and when the valve is opened, the water are continuously being released, and the pressure is being reduced accordingly, so the pressure is being reduced in a linear fashion. Is it the same with electricity? Is a power supply, let’s say a battery, a container of electrons, that the mere presence of them is what creates the voltage? Is it that when we apply voltage to a closed circuit, we “pour” the electrons from the battery to the circuit? Or is it more accurate to compare the electric circuit to a water in a closed circuit of pipes with a pump pushing the water in circles?
2. Voltage is defined as “The difference of potential energy, per unit of charge, between two points”. How is that compared to water in a tank? What notion of “difference” do we have in a water sitting in a tank?
3. The most difficult thing of understanding voltage for me is to get the idea of "difference" here. It is defined as “The difference of potential energy, per unit of charge, between two points”, and it is measured in Joules/Coulomb. So I understand that applying X volts to a circuit means that in this circuit, X Joules of energy can be transferred by every Coulomb of electrons (or more accurate to say - electric charge?) flowing in the circuit. But I don’t fully grasp the notion of “difference” here. Difference in what measure? The definition states that it is the “difference of potential electrical energy”. In what units “potential of electrical energy” measured? Is there an absolute value of “potential electrical energy” for each pole individually?  Is “potential electrical energy” equivalent to “electric charge”?

Comment: It's usually better here to focus on one question only, as otherwise it might get closed as "needs more focus".

Comment: Maybe the analogy of gravitational PE near the Earth's surface will help.  The potential energy is $U=mgh$, but the level from which we measure $h$ is arbitrary.  What we really mean is $\Delta U = mg \Delta y$.  So the *change in potential energy per unit mass* is $\Delta U /m = g\Delta y$ in analogy to what we have with charges $\Delta U/q = \Delta V$.  (if we lived on a planet where $g=1$, the equations would look exactly the same)   The pressure analogy has problems.  The height analogy is more like it.

Comment: @garyp, gravitational PE near the earth's surface, as far as I understand, refers to the amount of energy an object has when it falls a height of h. More accurately - the energy it transfers. How does this relate to pressure? Voltage is always compared to pressure being built in the water tank as a result of the presence of the water.

Comment: One usually thinks of pressure as a push that moves the water.  This is suggested by the usual development of pressure as atoms bouncing off of a wall, or as the transfer of momentum across a plane.  But in each of those scenarios there are atoms on the other side of the wall or plane working in the opposite direction so that net force or momentum transfer is zero. To get a net movement you need a *pressure difference*.  This is why I said that the pressure analogy has problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In a battery there is a chemical process separating charges, so the correct analogy would be a pump maintaining some height in the reservoir. The pump in this case would be that chemical process. Your version of a tank that drains is more anologous to a capacitor, where some charge is put onto it, and that charge is all there is. When all of it has run through the circuit, there is no more potential difference.
2. The difference in the analogy is the height of the water level in the tank, and the analogous potential is the gravitational potential energy of the water in the tank. The "per unit of charge" part translates to "per mass unit of water", because the mass is what is responsible for the stored potential energy.

> Difference in what measure?

Difference in energy. To go back to the water analogy, imagine you have a tank of water again. Here, instead of potential electrical energy, we have potential gravitational energy. The difference of the gravitational potential energy between the bottom and the top of the tank is the energy needed to take some amount (say 1 kg) of water and transport it to the top. Or, in reverse, how much energy does the same amount of water pick up when it comes down from that height. For electrical charge it's the same. Take 1 coulomb of charge from one pole of the battery, and measure how much energy you must put in / take out to get it to the other pole. So clearly *potential electrical energy* is measured in joules, just like any other energy. Usually, we don't really care about the joules alone, because that would somehow include the total charge in the battery, so we rather use joules per charge, i.e. joules per coulomb aka volts.

The *difference* in potential is always mentioned, because there is no absolute reference level (although we sometimes use ground potential for that). To use the water analogy one last time, if you have a water tank, it only matters how high the tank itself is, i.e. the *difference* between its lowest and highest point. Take your whole water circuit and lift it up by 10 meters, you still have the same circuit with the same potential. That's why it's only meaningful to talk about *differences* in electrical potential.

Comment: So you're saying that some mass (say 1 kg) in the top of the tank has x potential gravitational energy, and the same mass in the bottom of the tank has x-h gravitational potential energy. But we're talking about the pressure of the water in the pipe connected to the bottom of the tank, and I can't see how those things relate. It's been a while since my mechanics class back in the university, but my intuition tells me that this is more a function of the quantity of the water in the tank rather than the height of the tank.. isn't it?

Comment: No that's purely a function of the height, see [hydrostatic pressure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics#Hydrostatic_pressure).

Comment: It is of course assumed the tank is full. Or, alternatively, that the height is the difference between the lowest point and the highest point where there is water.

Comment: Just making sure - Considering 2 situations in which we have a tank of water with a hose of a certain diameter connected in the bottom, with water standing in a certain height. In the first situation the tank is 4 meters squared (so the volume of the water is 4*height_of_water), and in the second situation the tank is 8 meters squared (volume is 8*height_of_water). Is the pressure in the hose the same in both situations?

Comment: Yes, it's a classic unintuitive result about fluid pressure. It's even independent of the shape of the tank.

Comment: Ok, thanks for filling that hole :). But I still don't get it, is the pressure in the hose measured in terms of the difference in gravitational potential energy between the top of the tank and the bottom of the tank (which is, relatively to the hose, is 0 I suppose)? I can understand that the difference in height is relevant when talking about the gravitational potential energy of some object placed in some height above a level that it can fall to, but what is the connection between this and pressure?

Comment: The pressure in the in the hose is $p=\rho gh$, where $h$ is the height of the water column. $gh$ is the potential energy per unit mass at height $h$ above the reference level, so you see they only differ by the water density. I feel like this whole analogy is really only useful once you have properly understood hydrostatics, otherwise it's just trying to learn two things at once.

Answer (score -1):

The term "voltage" actually means "voltage drop between two points in a circuit".  It's the voltage drop which causes current flow, similar to the way that pressure drop causes fluid flow.